# How to refer String Bean in @ConditionalOnProperty

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, properties, annotations

I need to initialize a Configuration based on some other bean value that I am fetching from database,
how can we refer the bean in @ConditionalOnProperty value attribute ?

Or is there any other way to achieve the same.

```
// Bean that will query database
@Bean
public String checkAndCreate()
{
       // Logic to Query DB
       return "true";
}
```

`Want to Refer the bean checkAndCreate in value`

```
@ConditionalOnPropery(value = "", havingValue = "true")
@Configuration
public class MyConfiguration
{
      // Some configuration Code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `@ConditionalOnProperty`, use `@Conditional` with a custom condition instead. The `ConditionContext` should give you access to this bean. You may need to use `@DependsOn` on to ensure that the class providing the string bean is already initialized.